# C++ loop breaked 'cause the std::find algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, c++17, stl-algorithm

I have the next C++ code snippet:

```
...
static constexpr const char* my_char_array [10] { // Some literals here... } // Member of a class
std::vector<std::string> splitted_input { // Contains C++ strings }
std::vector<std::string> matched_keywords { // The coincident ones will be copied here }

for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(this->my_char_array); i++) {
    std::cout << "Comparing: " << this->my_char*_array[i] << std::endl;
    auto value = std::find(splitted_input.begin(), splitted_input.end(), (std::string) this->my_char_array[i]);
    if ( value != end(splitted_input) ) {
        matched_keywords.push_back(this->keywords[i]);
    }
}
```

I am iterating over an `const char*`, looking for a literal that could be inside a `vec<string>`.
When I use the std::find algorithm, the for loop stops on the first iteration (std::cout just outputs the first value on `my_char*_array`).

Never faced an issue like that. Any idea?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: Please post an [mcve] instead of incomplete pseudocode, otherwise it’s not really possible to diagnose bugs.

Comment: `my_char*_array`? That's not a valid name. Please create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: Also, remember that the `sizeof` operator will return the size of the object in *bytes*. For an array it will only return the number of elements if the array is an array of `char` (not `char*` but plain `char`).

Comment: You probably want `sizeof(this->my_char_array)/sizeof(this->my_char_array[0])`, to get size of `my_char_array` array

Comment: Its safer to use std::array : `static constexpr std::array<const char*, 2> my_char_array = {"dsds", "dddd"};` and `my_char_array.size()`

Comment: @marcinj Both or your responses made my day. If you want to elaborate a full response with your data, explaining better the usecases for upcoming visitors, I will mark your answer as approved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(this->my_char_array); i++) {
```

you are using `sizeof` operator which is returning number of bytes which `my_char_array` occupies, and this is equal to size of pointer (8 bytes on x64 system) multiplied by number of pointers in your array. So this code is iterating over more elements than actually are in you array which is causing UB (undefined behaviour). The usual solution is to divide by element size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(this->my_char_array)/sizeof(this->my_char_array[0]); i++) {
```

or even better, replace array with `std::array`, example:

```
static constexpr std::array<const char*, 2> my_char_array = {"dsds", "dddd"};
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_char_array.size(); i++) {
```

and don't forget to `#include <array>`

Comment: What a nice answer. Thaks for your time!

Comment: @Pyzyryab no problem :-)